# How can I produce the git diff omitting changes that are in master?

Tags: git

So I was hinted at there being options to review diffs omitting changes from a specific branch using some cherry picking options but I'm still lost on this and would appreciate an actual command to achieve this.

I want to review revision spans on a feature branch without being distracted by changes that come from merging master.

Suppose Anton does:

```
git checkout featureX // featureX is a long living branch
[do changes and commits]
git merge master
[do more changes and commits]
git push
```

Now if Berta does

```
git checkout featureX
git pull
```

git tells her

```
Updating 437b2899c..bffdf1a1f
```

and when she now does

```
git difftool --dir-diff 437b2899c..bffdf1a1f
```

the diff might be cluttered with changes from `master`. How can she hide changes from `master` in this diff?

To elaborate ...

Suppose commit `X` is the merge base (last commit on both `master` and `featureX`) and I already reviewed the next 100 commits on `featureX` up to commit `Y` at which point the dev did more commits and also merged `master` into `featureX` which also had 100 new commits that I already have reviewed. I don't want to re-review those commits from neither branch. `git diff X..featureX` contains both the 100 commits from `master` and from `featureX` that I already reviewed. `git diff Y..featureX` contains the 100 "old" commits from `master`. `git diff master..featureX` contains the 100 "old" commits from `featureX`. I want a diff with no changes introduced by any of these 200 "old" commits.

Comment: So you're saying you want a diff containing the changes this branch introduces, if we disregard changes done in master since the branch was created? Then you would compare against the mergebase before the pull.

Comment: "merge base" is the last commit both branches have in common but I want to skip earlier commits (that I already reviewed earlier), too. So `git diff master..featureX` is not what I want.

Comment: You can only compare an actual snapshot in an actual commit to any other actual snapshot in any other actual commit, or to a proposed snapshot in your (or any, really) index, or to some work-tree. In other words, there is no shortcut for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have this history (time flows left to right):

```
--X--o--o--o--o--Z--o       <- master
   \              \
    a--b--c--Y--r--s--t     < featureX
```

You have aready reviewed `abc`, `Y`, the `o`s and `Z`. Now you want to see only the diff generated by `rst`.

You cannot do this with a `git diff` command alone. The simplest is possibly to look at the individual diffs of `rst`:

```
git log -p Y..featureX ^master
```

If you really want to see one huge diff, you have to create an auxiliary merge commit that subsumes all commits that you are not interested in:

```
git checkout --detach Z
git merge Y
# if necessary, resolve conflicts and commit the merge
```

At this point, all uninteresting commits are in the merge commit:

```
                 ,-M        <- auxiliary commit
                / /
--X--o--o--o--o+-Z--o       <- master
   \          /   \
    a--b--c--Y--r--s--t     < featureX
```

Now you can generate the diff that subsumes `rst`:

```
git diff ..featureX
```

Comment: While this answer is really educative, it didn't help me much so far and I'm losing hope there is an easy hack for what I want to achieve. After resolving 20 merge conflicts, `git diff ..featureX | wc -l` > `git log -p Y..featureX ^master | wc -l` in my case :(. 6531 vs. 6109. I find that very surprising.

Comment: Indeed. `Z` is `git merge-base master featureX`, i.e. the last commit of `master` that was merged into `featureX`. Did you pick the correct one? In particular, `Z` is *not necessarily* the current head of `master`.

Comment: In my case, `git log --oneline Y..featureX | wc -l` is 1636 while `git log --oneline Y..featureX ^master | wc -l` is 31. Annoyingly much to review. In addition, your `git log -p Y..featureX ^master` approach skips the conflict resolutions of merge conflicts? This might be the explanation for my first comment's discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

> So I was hinted at there being options to review diffs omitting changes from a specific branch using some cherry picking options

They were probably talking about reviewing the diffs using `git-log`, since `git-diff` doesn't have any such options, while [`git-log` does](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry-pick).

In this case, you can use `git-log` with the [double-dot notation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_double_dot) and the [`--ancestry-path`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ancestry-path) option to select the commits you want to review.

From the documentation [about the double-dot notation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_double_dot):

> This basically asks Git to resolve a range of commits that are reachable from one commit but aren’t reachable from another.

By adding the `--ancestry-path` option, we're telling Git to only consider the commits that are *both* descendants of the first commit and ancestors of the second one.

The complete command would then be:

```
git log --patch --ancestry-path --no-merges Y..featureX
```

which literally means *select the non-merge commits that are both descendants of `Y` and ancestors of `featureX`*, then generate the patch for each of them.

In your case, it will show you the diffs introduced by the commits that only exist between `Y` and `featureX` on the `featureX` branch.

Comment: Skipping the merges is probably not what I want, as for a security review, I can't ignore "conflict resolutions" and indeed, comparing your approach with j6t's, I get less output than with j6t's approach but it's exactly 5 lines less: the list of the 5 merges which all show no diff there neither omit actual conflict resolutions, too.